# In TCL, how to remove a substring in a string and also have to do it for different string in a file

Tags: string, scripting, tcl

In Tcl, I have tried to remove a substring in a string through the below expression but
currently, I had to repeat the same command, again and again, to remove a different substring, from different strings so it wasn't the effective way, I wanted a better way of doing it,
Is it possible to write it in a single expression

```
file.v
   axi_p_awaddr_reg
   s_ph_awlen_i_reg
   l_ha_awsize_reg
   s_axi_wdata_reg

set k [format {%s} [string map {{_awaddr} {}} $k]]
set k [format {%s} [string map {{_awsize} {}} $k]]
set k [format {%s} [string map {{_wdata} {}} $k]]
set k [format {%s} [string map {{_awlen} {}} $k]]
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Python and bash?

Comment: No good reason I can see, so I removed those tags

Comment: The description says "remove a different substring, from different strings" but the code is removing different substrings from the same string, which of these is actually required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the requirement is really to remove multiple substrings from one string k, you can just do:

```
set k [string map {_awaddr {} _awsize {} _wdata {} _awlen {}} $k]
```